# How to round two of the four corners in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How to round two of the four corners in AS3? The function

```
drawRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, 16);
```

rounds all corners, but i need only 2 top corners or only 2 bottom corners.

Comment: Workaround: create two boxes. one with rounded corners, one without rounded cornes. Position the un-rounded box so that it hides the rounded cornes of the rounded box. Alternatively, google for a source of a similar function and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawRoundRectComplex` in the [mx.utils.GraphicsUtil](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/GraphicsUtil.html) allows you to specify topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, and bottomRightRadius separately.

Example:

`GraphicsUtil.drawRoundRectComplex(this.graphics,0,0,width,height,20,20,0,0);`